# multivariate partial fraction decomposition python

Tags: python, math

I have a problem with the multivariate partial fraction decomposition in python.
After 50 try of changing the syntax it is still not working. What do i need to modify ?

```
import sympy.polys.partfrac
from sympy.abc import x

f = (x - 3)/((x - 1)**5*(x**2 - 1)*(x**2 + 1))

print((sympy.polys.partfrac.apart(f)))
```

Comment: x^x is not a polynomial

Comment: oh i see it is a x**2

Comment: @JaredGoguen you solved it